# Get the id of an entity in JPA without pulling the entity from the database?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

Suppose I have the following two JPA entities which have a one to one relationship

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
  @Id 
  private Integer id; 

  @Column(...)
  private String data;
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
    @Id 
    private Integer id; 

    @OneToOne(fetchType=LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="foo_fk")
    private Foo foo; 

    @Column(...)
    private String x; 

    @Column(...)
    private String y; 
}
```

What I want to do is find all the Bar entities that meet some search criteria for example `SELECT Bar b FROM Bar WHERE b.x = :xValue` What i want to do is iterate the result set and extract the the primary key of foo and the value y i.e. code along the lines of.

```
List<Bar> results = // query to get all the results that meet value x 
for(Bar bar: results) {
    String x = bar.getX();
    String y = bar.getY();
    Integer fooId = bar.getFoo().getId(); // at this point Hibernate pulls back foo from the db 
    // do something with x,y and fooId 
 }
```

What I want to avoid is having the ORM issue a SELECT for when i do `bar.getFoo().getId()`
. I know that I can do a report query along the lines of `SELECT new com.example.MyResult(b.x,b.y,b.foo.id) FORM Bar b WHERE b.x = :xValue`

Is there a way to to avoid the select on `bar.getFoo().getId()`without writing a report query? I am using Hibernate 3.6.10 and JPA 2 I am happy to upgrade to Hibernate 4.1.x if it can do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT b.foo.id FROM Bar b WHERE b.x = :something
```

This will give you just the IDs, but there's no guarantee as to how the ORM layer will obtain them. If you want absolute control over the native queries, then write them yourself.

Comment: Atleast with Hibernate + Postgres it will not pull back the whole object (which I assume is your concern). He could probably guarantee this by making his select select constant or have a dummy inner join.

Comment: @Adam can you give an example of the technique using the dummy inner join?

Answer (score 0):

The `foo` association from Bar is apparently lazy, making it eager will help.